# Restore OS X iMessages History from chat.db

Tags: macos, sqlite, restore, imessage

I saved a copy of everything inside `~/Library/Messages/` which included a folder named
`Attachments` that is filled with a bunch of subdirectories containing all my files ever attached to a message (images, documents, movies, etc),  and three (3) files named:

1. `chat.db` (about 20 MB file size),
2. `chat.db-shm` (33 KB), and
3. `chat.db-wal` (565 KB).

I opened the large `chat.db` file and it contains all my messages in an SQLite database. I know this file contains all the information needed to rebuild my iMessage history, I'm just not sure how to convince the iMessages.app to do so.

I've been at this for about 60 minutes now, trying several different things (I'm not going to list out every one of them).

There's gotta be a way to restore my messages from these files that I saved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

After banging my head on it for 3 days - I've found out the following:

All those 3 files keep an index of what you have in Archives. So removing corrupted files and/or just restoring backup of these 3 files *should* have done it. But it didn't. I've tried restarting Messages app a thousand times after replacing those files, to no avail. Until I've decided to run `lsof` to see what is actually using `chat.db`. To my surprise it was *not* Messages app:

```
[none-none][18:42:24] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/Library/Messages)$ lsof -n | grep chat.db
IMDPersis 1655 vlazarenko  txt       REG                1,3      32768 107632436 /Users/vlazarenko/Library/Messages/chat.db-shm
IMDPersis 1655 vlazarenko    4u      REG                1,3     309032 107632435 /Users/vlazarenko/Library/Messages/chat.db-wal
IMDPersis 1655 vlazarenko    5u      REG                1,3       4096 107632432 /Users/vlazarenko/Library/Messages/chat.db
IMDPersis 1655 vlazarenko    6u      REG                1,3      32768 107632436 /Users/vlazarenko/Library/Messages/chat.db-shm
```

As you can see, it's a process called `IMDPersis`something.. Looking for that one:

```
[none-none][18:57:10] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/Library/Messages)$ ps -ef | grep IMDPersis
  501  1655     1   0  6:48PM ??         0:00.11 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMDPersistence.framework/XPCServices/IMDPersistenceAgent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/IMDPersistenceAgent
```

An a-ha! moment. Quitting Messages, replacing the files, doing `kill` on the PID of `IMDPersistenceAgent` and then starting Messages got me my history back in no time.

Thought I'd share, albeit this is an old thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is some helpful information on the Apple discussion forum.

Basically, just need to move a backed-up `~Library/Messages` folder to replace the new empty `~Library/Messages` folder.

It may be that `chat.db`, `chat.db-shm` and `chat.db-wal` files are linked together with keys etc., so that may be the reason iMessages is not accepting the changes.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5378830

Comment: I've tried about 10 different solutions all of which led to no results. In fact, after trying the final time, I gave up...I started accumulating my current messages and after a few days I restarted my system and when it booted back my latest messages were gone, I had to start over!

Comment: I just moved the whole folder and it seemed to work ok for me. I followed the recommended procedures, ie. reboot before opening iMessages etc.